# How to create an App with a lot of media without getting memory problems?

Tags: android

i should create app for tablets, which will be shows magazines, every magazine will be have about 60-70 pages, every page has cover as image ( weight about 400kB - 1mb, height over 1200px and width = screen size ), and every page has small cover ( about 20kB ), some pages have mp3, mov and other files, which I must show on this page. When i start first time app, i must download about 200mb, now but in future will be more files, magazines, and pages ;(

When I open magazine, i must load about 70 pages and when i slide screen, pages will be move right - left. When I click on screen, I must show gallery view with small images cover.

Im wondering, that it will be waste of time to create this app, any ideas how i could show images and other files whithout overload memory ? Have You any experience in app like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it: will any user of your app ever see more than one page at once?

To put it even further, when was the last time you did actually read 70 pages simultaneously?

The key to implementing such an app is clever loading and unloading data as it is needed. There are quite some strategies to achieve this, one very simple would be to keep only a few pages (the last, the current and maybe the next two) in memory at a time. This makes switching pages seamless and keeps your memory footprint low. It can be quite hard to figure out the right balance between memory use and responsiveness, but well, thats what it takes. Good luck.

Comment: I agree. This would definitely not be a project for a beginner. I foresee a lot of multithreading and while Android offers a lot of background utility classes, it can still be confusing if you don't have a good design laid out.

Comment: any user see one page at once, but when clicked on screen, gallery view is shows with 70 small covers, but this is no problem yet. the for answer.

Comment: Well implementing a gallery view is still a different beast. However, you won't have to load all media for this, too. Maybe it wouldn't even have to be an absolutely exact thumbnail view at all. But that depends strongly on the app/layout/etc pp and can also be a demanding task to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Your application can contain any number of information within itself, but to display correctly you shouldn't immediately load all media files. Currently displayed in only the informations you need. Many standard controls initially work as well (table with reused cells, for example). Small pictures can be cached in memory, when switching between pages removes all  old information and upload a new one.
Just start it and success won't keep waiting.

Comment: i didnt show all media files, just 3 images, small images i cached in memory using lazy load images, but memory is my the bigest enemy ;/